# Cannot add color to text in Python

Tags: python

Here is a simplified version of the code I am trying to  run:

`print "My name is \033[1;34m%s\033[1;m" % name`

However, when I try to run this, it prints

`My name is [1;34mBob[1;m`

It appears that the backslash only escapes the 0 instead of escaping the 033. How do I fix this problem without having to download an external module? Thanks!

Comment: It works for me (macOS Terminal.app, Python 2.7.16, `xterm-256color`). What terminal emulator are you using? What's the output of `echo $TERM`, etc?

Comment: Changing colors gets tricky in Windows. I would use one of the libraries mentioned in [how-to-print-colored-text-in-terminal-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-in-terminal-in-python)

Comment: @grooveplex I'm using Windows Command Prompt. That might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if you are using Windows, I would recommend this:

[How to print colored text in terminal in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-in-terminal-in-python)

The answers should work on Windows. But, in general, these work for Windows and should work for every other operating system. So, the answer with highest vote says that what it suggested should work on Windows 10. So if you are using Windows 10, then that should work for you.